# Can the mySQL database store the curent timestamp into a different format?

Tags: mysql

Is it possible that the mySQL database stores the current timestamp in a different format (when a new insert is made?)
This is how the date is automatically created:

> 2015-06-18 11:00:11

What I would like to have in my table column is:

> 1506

Is this possible and how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I found almost a solution:

```
INSERT INTO `Lines` (`date`) VALUES (NOW());
```

But it is storing now:

> 2015